# Apache camel: filter / throttle to take just the first message from a queue

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl, throttling

What's the simplest way to take just the first message from a queue?

Given that there is nothing I can see in the header to filter on (no sequence numbers, or the like, at least as far as I can see), is there anything better than this?

```
from("webspheremq:topic:SNAPSHOTS")
    .throttle(1).timePeriodMillis(1234567890L * 1000)
    .to("direct:anotherqueue")
```

Prefer camel DSL over beans + java code :)

**Edit**

actually reading from a webspheremq topic.

**Edit2**

don't use `Long.MAX_VALUE` as the time period! Try 1234567890L * 1000 instead

Comment: I'm curious about the use case?

Comment: The use case is that a large message (a snapshot of data) is received on a queue (well, actually, it's a topic). Other users who request a snapshot will peculiarily trigger another snapshot to be sent to all consumers. Weird behaviour, but I must handle it in this manner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to filter using a singleton holding first-ness state:

```
public static class FirstOrNot {
    private static FirstOrNot _instance;

    public synchronized boolean isfirst() {
        if ( _instance == null ) {
            _instance = new FirstOrNot();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

FirstOrNot first = new FirstOrNot();

from("webspheremq:topic:SNAPSHOTS")
    .filter().method( first , "isFirst" )
    .to("direct:anotherqueue")
```

Perhaps you can use this as a starting point.

Cheers,

Comment: Yes, great, thanks! I also added a method `reset()`, since I needed it.